# PowerApps Filter Gallery and Search Function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a gallery which has a search box attached to it with the following formula
Search('Incident Report', TextInputSearchBox.Text,"Title")

I now also now want to add the following filter function to the gallery
Filter('Incident Report', Lower('Notified Users'.Email) = Lower(User().Email)

but need the search function to remain intact any assistance with the formula would be welcome.  For info data is gallery data is pulling from a SharePoint list.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the result of a Search function into the Filter function (or vice-versa). In your case, it would look somewhat like the expression below:

```
Search(
    Filter('Incident Report', Lower('Notified Users'.Email) = Lower(User().Email)),
    TextInputSearchBox.Text,
    "Title")
```

or

```
Filter(
    Search('Incident Report', TextInputSearchBox.Text, "Title"),
    Lower('Notified Users'.Email) = Lower(User().Email))
```

Comment: Thank you,  I have tried this but seem to get a formula error message.  The filter and the search both work independent to each other but when combined as per the above I get the following error:   Incompatible types for comparison.  These types cant be compared in the formula: Table, Text.   We cant evaluate your formula because the values being compared in the formula aren't the same type.   Location: GalIncReport.Items